# Notetaking app that can sync between Android and Linux on wireless and NOT using any online services?

Tags: linux, android, notes

I don't mind if it needs some hacking. I am using, on Linux, elementary OS's Footnote, which I like very much.

If I could use it's database file somehow in Android, that would be great. Is there a way to do so, or perhaps another app that allows wireless syncing between Android and Linux?

Comment: What's the difference between a “notetaking app” and a text editor?

Comment: Not much. In Footnote there are notebooks, and in that, notes. So it is organized.

Comment: And how does that differ from putting files in directories? Both Android and Linux have a ton of text editors, so that would reduce the problem to syncing files.

Comment: Changing directories and open them one by one is not for me. I would like to see them all at once. Like in footnote. Here is a sample. http://imgur.com/du7PfPt